# Proving the existence of disjoint subsets

Tags: combinatorics

Let $A$ be a set of cardinality $n$ and let $A_1,...,A_{n+1}$ be subsets of $A$.  Prove that there are disjoint nonempty $I,J\subset\{1,...,n+1\}$ satisfying $$\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i=\bigcup_{j\in J}A_j.$$

I've been stuck on this problem for awhile - not quite sure how to start.  Thus far in the course we've been studying vector spaces, subspaces, bases, etc.

Edit: I noticed the question has been re-tagged as "combinatorics", but it should be noted I have never taken a course in combinatorics (this question is from an algebra course) and so  I have no familiarity with many of its concepts.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is true. Let's set $n = 2$, $A = \{1, 2, 3\}$ and $A_k = \{k\}$ for $k \in \{1,2,3\}$. Can you find disjoint and nonempty $I$ and $J$?

Comment: @LeonAragones: your set $A$ does not have $n=2$ elements.

Comment: Oh, I see: it is time to go to bed. A hint for the OP: use the pigeonhole principle.

Comment: Count amount of choices for $I$ and amount of options for $\bigcup_{i\in I} A_i$.

Comment: So would the number of choices for I, J be $n!$?  Unsure of the number of options for the union, would it be $n!$ as well?

Comment: You have to be a little more careful than this. While there are $2^{n+1}$ choices for $I$ and only $2^n$ choices for the union, that only tells you there must be lots of pairs $I$ and $J$ which give the same union -- but it doesn't guarantee that $I$ and $J$ will be disjoint.

Comment: Ah I see, using the Power set.  Now I see how to use the Pidgeonhle Principle.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $I$ and $J$ are constrained to be nonempty, the assertion may in fact be false if one of the $A_i$'s is empty (for example, $n=2$, $A_1=\{1\}$, $A_2=\{2\}$, $A_3=\emptyset$.)  On the other hand, if at least two $A_i$'s are empty (say $A_i$ and $A_j$), we win by choosing $I=\{i\}$ and $J=\{j\}$.  So we will assume henceforth that all of the $A_i$'s are nonempty, and we prove the result under this assumption.

Write down the "incidence matrix" $M$, which has $n+1$ rows, corresponding to the $A_i$'s, and $n$ columns, corresponding to the elements of the set $A$, as follows: in the row corresponding to the set $A_i$, put a $1$ in each column corresponding to an element of $A_i$, and zeros in the remaining columns.  As there are more rows than columns, the rows must be linearly dependent, so there's a row vector ${\vec c}=(c_1,\ldots,c_{n+1})$ such that ${\vec c}\, M=0$, with the $c_i$'s not all zero.

Define $I=\{ i\mid c_i>0\}$ and $J=\{j\mid c_j<0\}$.
If ${\vec a_i}$ denotes the row vector corresponding to the set $A_i$, we then have
$$\sum_{i\in I}c_i {\vec a_i}=\sum_{j\in J}|c_j| {\vec a_j}.$$
Call this sum $\vec u$, and note that all coefficients in the sum are positive.
Since none of the $A_i$'s are empty, $\vec u$ is a nonzero vector with nonnegative coordinates, so both $I$ and $J$ are nonempty (and they're clearly disjoint.)

A coordinate in the left-hand sum is nonzero precisely when it is nonzero in some $\vec a_i$ with $i\in I$, so the nonzero coordinates of $\vec u$ correspond precisely to the elements of $\cup_{i\in I}A_i$.  But the same is true on the right-hand side, so we conclude that
$\cup_{i\in I}A_i = \cup_{j\in J}A_j.$